# Nodemon in VM does not see changes when file edited from host machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, nodemon

I have a `node` app which I run inside virtual machine (Virtualbox, Vagrant, Ubuntu) using `nodemon` for development purposes.

The files are located in `vagrant`'s shared folder.

When I change an app js file inside virtual machine - nodemon restarts the node app.
But when I change the same file from host machine (Max OS X Yosemite) - the app would not restart.

In similar situation when host was Windows 10 - it worked fine.

I start nodemon through `Grunt` with config

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var cfg = {

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                script: 'src/server.js'
            },
            options: {
                nodeArgs: ['--harmony'],
                ext: 'js,json,hbs',
                ignore: [
                    'public/**',
                    'node_modules/**',
                    '.git/**'
                ]
            }
        }
    };

    grunt.initConfig(cfg);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['nodemon']);

};
```

Or directly `nodemon ./src/server.js localhost 3000`

What am I missing?

Comment: where is nodemon installed?

Comment: It is installed in VM: The node is in dir /node, so nodemon is in `/node/lib/node_modules/nodemon`. It is visible if you execute if from console: `nodemon -v` results in : `1.8.1`

Comment: As a workaround, you can try watching the files for change on the host machine and find a way to restart the server remotely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995590/auto-starting-node-js-application-on-vagrant-when-there-are-changes-to-the-code

Answer (score 9):

Try to use parameter `-L` for `nodemon` or `Grunt`'s config parameter `legacyWatch: true` in your `options` section.

Details could be found [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting).

Comment: The `-L` flag consumed too much CPU for me.

Comment: what does ```-L``` flag do. or what is ```legacy watch```

Comment: If you don't want to use polling you need to consider other tools like https://github.com/AgentCosmic/xnotify which was designed to work for vagrant

Comment: is there a similar solution for browser-sync?